# How can you get Finder to sort by name, but also sort folders before files?

Tags: finder, sort

When I want sort my files and folder in Finder (specially sort by name) they sort all item by name mixing folders and files together. I want a way that sorts (like Windows) first all folders by name then all other items by name. How can I do this?

Comment: Sierra now has this feature - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54759/how-do-you-get-mac-os-finder-to-group-folders-together-when-sorting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no built in feature in the Finder to achieve that, but with the "plugin" [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) you can get that. It's located under the "Tweaks" tab in the TotalFinder settings.

Edit: There was a screenshot here, but it was out of date. Look at [Robsofts answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-sort-by-name-in-finder-but-first-sort-folders-then-files/317#317) instead for an up-to-date screenshot!

Comment: I install it but I can't find my answer in this program.
1- my install version was newer than you and my Tweaks setting is different from yours.
2-it's in alpha version and expire then it's not good for me.
3-can you explain which part is related to my answer?

Comment: I too have the latest version, but I have swedish as my system language so a screenshot from my computer would probably be even more confusing. But in the latest version it's still the setting that's located second to top in the Tweaks tab.
And when the alpha expire there will probably be a new one released or the final version will be released, which will cost 15$ according to the developers website.

Comment: Thanks for the link to TotalFinder, I'm finding it very useful already. I like the hidden files view - nice and grey rather than same colour as normal files, and the tabs are proving useful too.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - see my answer below for a picture of the current tweaks screen.

Answer (score 5):

[XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) is free plugin for Finder that allows you to sort folders before files, by selecting "Arrange folders on top" in the Preferences.

After installing and running it, you can tune folder sorting and many other aspects of Finder behavior.

Comment: this is a great solution, as it's not a hack, lets you continue using Finder, and it's free.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/67100/force-your-mac-to-put-folders-on-top-of-files-windows-style/) is a method that involves a plist setting, and no plugin, or third party app.

To summarize:

> Show Package Contents of Finder.app (located in `System/Library/CoreServices`
>
> Drill down to `Contents > Resources > English.lproj. > InfoPlist.strings`
>
> Locate the string `“Folder” = “Folder”;`
>
> Add a leading space before the second `Folder` as follows: `“Folder” = “ Folder”;`
>
> Save `InfoPlist.strings` to the same location (backup elsewhere if desired)
>
> Relaunch Finder (`Ctrl+Option+Click`)
>
> Open new Finder window and sort files by Kind

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: I will check your solution when I have time, and if it works for me I'll change the accepted answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for El-Capitan (Finder version 10.11).
Is there an updated solution for this problem that doesn't involve any plugin or app?

Comment: As of El Capitan and later there is no need anymore to patch anything as the option to sort guides first has been added to the Finder settings. This solution is **DEPRECATED**.

Answer (score 3):

Related to the Total Finder answer above (so please don't vote for this answer), here's a picture of the current TF tweaks page (you get to it from the Finder's Preferences screen). With these options I definitely get the folders at the top of the list.

You can also control this from the VIEW menu in Finder, once TF is installed.

[image: Snapshot of current Total Finder tweaks screen]

Comment: Tanx for your help, but why don't vote for your answer?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - TotalFinder was @Nagon's answer really - if you were allowed to paste images into comments then I would have just put this image below his/her answer. :-)

Comment: ok I got it, but I vote you for your help, and accept and vote @nagon answer.

Comment: @robsoft - If you don't mind I can put your image in my answer or at least point to your answer in some way? :)

Comment: @Nagon - by all means, be my guest! :-)

Comment: @robsoft I linked to your answer, thanks for contributing with a proper screenshot! :)

Answer (score 3):

As of OS X Yosemite (≥ 10.10), you can sort folders above files without any third-party apps.

Finder > Preferences -> Advanced tab -> Check "Keep folders on top: in windows when sorting by name" option.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Finder replacement called [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) that will do what you want. It's a bit more expensive but it does do a lot more than just a regular finder window.

Comment: +1 to sole your -1, because I thought your answer was related. I don't know who give you -1 and why!

Comment: but it was not what I mean, path finder was a separate program and also didn't what I want!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by having icons displayed as list (Cmd + 2) in Finder window. First click on the [Name] column header (this will sort all files by name), then click on [Kind] column header (this will sort items by kind, but keep the name sorting in groups).

Comment: This won't just sort out files, it will group by file type. Folders won't appear first and all file types will be separately sorted.

Comment: it's a nice trick, but I want can do this in all form not just in cmd + 2 form. but tanx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have found myself doing the `Folder` trick over and over again I ended up creating a bash script to automate renaming of the string in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`.

1. Save it as e.g. `finder-folders-first.sh`
2. Make it executable: `chmod +x finder-folders-first.sh`
3. Run with root permissions: `sudo finder-folders-first.sh`

```or-tag-here
#!/bin/bash
# Make folders sortable first in Finder

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "Script must be run as root! Aborting."
   exit 1
fi

cd /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/

cp -i InfoPlist.strings InfoPlist_ORIGINAL-`date +%b-%d-%Y_%H_%M_%S`.strings
plutil -convert xml1 InfoPlist.strings
sed 's|<string>Folder</string>|<string> Folder</string>|' InfoPlist.strings > InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings

diff InfoPlist.strings InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo File already patched! Exiting.
    exit -1
else
    echo Patching original file...
    plutil -convert binary1 InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings -o InfoPlist.strings

fi
echo Restarting Finder...
killall Finder
echo Done!
```

The last line restarts Finder. To do the same thing from the GUI press Alt+rightclick the Finder icon in the Dock and select <kbd>Relaunch</kbd>.

Now, in Finder click the *Kind* column once/twice to have the folders listed as first/last.

This works in Mavericks and Yosemite, but might not work in later versions.

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution! Sadly did not work on El Capitan though - `InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings: file does not exist or is not readable or is not a regular file (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=InfoPlist_PATCHED.strings, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9c78d09bd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})`