# How does finder sort folders when they contain digits and characters?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, sort

I can't figure it out how to sort folders by name in Finder.

My expected results should look like this:

```
0629e7bc-8110-4db9-aaa9-b67b0b73743d
06a409e1-98c6-4bf4-afa4-c814f7899d82
0a3a5c12-e459-4aa0-b9cb-30b544013215
0c14581f-31d8-4961-a14f-11afc40e47f9
0fe8970c-6338-46ca-bc16-f7867b271480
129855c4-7dbe-4a9f-a100-28b1d3d02340
1522e288-8a81-4298-aefc-f334cb088a53
180d430b-76f9-401f-845a-cb395bc1eba0
1a01a936-bedf-4758-971a-d4886ee8d281
....
```

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

Here are my settings:

[image: sorting]

Grouping is turned off.

I think this is a bug. [Grouping is turned off everywhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289/) (grouping doesn't change anything here). I've deleted `.DS_Store` files.

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132)

Even if I switch to another view, it does not work.

[image: another screenshot]

What else could I try to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is alphabetical vs natural search order being used in Terminal(or wherever the code block comes from) and Finder respectively.

> Why is a folder which starts with a 2 on the bottom?

Because it is 27 which is treated as a block while sorting and is greater than other single numbers which are also being treated as blocks. Another example is in the longer screenshot. `5f` comes before `06a` as 5 is smaller than 06.

Numbers are *smaller than* alphabets in both cases.

In the code block, we have character-wise sorting where single digits are being compared. So a larger number like `062` sometimes comes before `06a` as 2 is smaller than a.

> For example, in alphabetical sorting "z11" would be sorted before "z2"
>   because "1" is sorted as smaller than "2", while in natural sorting
>   "z2" is sorted before "z11" because "2" is sorted as smaller than
>   "11".
>
> Alphabetical sorting:
>
> `z11`
>
> `z2`
>
> Natural sorting:
>
> `z2`
>
> `z11`
>
> Functionality to sort by natural sort order is built into many
>   programming languages and libraries

<sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order</sup>

> Mac OS X sorting is based on the Unicode Collation Algorithm (Technical Standard UTS #10) defined by the Unicode Consortium. This standard provides a complete and unambiguous sort ordering for all Unicode characters and is available on the Unicode Consortium website (http://www.unicode.org).

There are no hints that this behaviour can be changed in Finder. It was observed in 2002-03:

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021002061850171
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375244/313842 Comments under here suggest using apps like Pathfinder.
- <sup>https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/SortingRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002377-BCIJIGDE</sup>
- <sup>https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemDetails/FileSystemDetails.html</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101267/discussion-on-answer-by-ankii-cannot-sort-folders-in-finder-by-name).